# ASP.NET Configuration Wizard to login with remote sql server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, createuserwizard

I have been learning ASP.NET by experimenting, watching videos on ASP.NET, and reading forums.  I haven't found a quick solution to this though.

Whenever I add the "login" or "createuserwizard" from the toolbox it always adds the new users to a database known as "ASPNETDB.MDF" even if I specify the remote database using a new SqlDataSource.

Is there an easy way to save the login information?  Any tutorials that helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET will use a local file based database to store the login information.

If you want to use a different database, you need to do a couple of things:

1. Set up the Remote Database using [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) (usually found in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727) - running this will start it in GUI mode, allowing you select a server and database to add the tables and stored procs to.
2. Configure your web site to use this database. There are a few of places you need to do this:

In the ConnectionStrings section of the web.config add your new ConnectionString:

```
<add 
  name="zhpCoreContentConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=Hobbiton\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=zhpCoreContent;Integrated Security=True" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

In the [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx) section of the web.config, ensure the ConnectionString attribute is set to the same name as your connection string (other settings elided for berevity):

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add 
      connectionStringName="zhpCoreContentConnectionString"
      applicationName="/doodle"
      name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

If you are using [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164660.aspx) or [Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164644.aspx) you'll want to ensure that they are also using your connectionstring to store everything together, and ensure that the applicationName attribute is common between them.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I get the error:

The entry 'AspNetSqlMembershipProvider' has already been added.

Comment: Ah, once again I do appreciate your help.  It enabled me to find this page:
http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=743&pId=-1

and now I have a remote login.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need to [Implement a Custom Membership user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(VS.80).aspx)